# Grouping Prometheus Monitored Targets and Rules

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Currently, monitoring is established for 10 environments with 10 rules, and incident emails are directed to a specific email address. However, additionally, I would like to configure 3 specific environments with only 3 rules to send incident emails to a different email address.

Below is the current code for the alert manager.
Please instruct me on how to add the configuration here.

```
global:
  smtp_smarthost: 'email-smtp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:111'
  smtp_from: 'Alertmanager <aaa@abcd.jp>'
  smtp_auth_username: 'ASDFGHJKLQWERTYUIO'
  smtp_auth_password: 'hfiytOUYiuhlIYFTDilkUTFRDikhgfG'
#  smtp_auth_secret: '*********'

route:
  # デフォルトレシーバー
  receiver: 'default'

  # 同一アラート名、インスタンス名、エラーレベルでグループ化。アラートを同じ種類とみなす条件
  group_by: ['alertname', 'instance', 'severity']

  # 同じ種類のアラートを1つのアラート群としてにまとめる時間
  group_wait: 30s

  # 同じ種類のアラートが発生した時に次回通知するまでの時間(リカバリー通知も)
  group_interval: 5m

  # 一度通知したアラートは1時間おきに通知
  repeat_interval: 1h
 
  routes:
    # アラートによって送信先を変更
    - match:
        severity: critical
        
      # 同一アラート名、インスタンス名、エラーレベルでグループ化。アラートを同じ種類とみなす条件
      group_by: ['alertname', 'instance', 'severity']

      # 同じ種類のアラートを1つのアラート群としてにまとめる時間
      group_wait: 30s

      # 同じ種類のアラートが発生した時に次回通知するまでの時間(リカバリー通知も)
      group_interval: 5m

      # 一度通知したアラートは1時間おきに通知
      repeat_interval: 1h

      # レシーバ対応先
      receiver: critical

    - match:
        severity: warning

      # 同一アラート名、インスタンス名、エラーレベルでグループ化。アラートを同じ種類とみなす条件
      group_by: ['alertname', 'instance', 'severity']

      # 同じ種類のアラートを1つのアラート群としてにまとめる時間
      group_wait: 30s

      # 同じ種類のアラートが発生した時に次回通知するまでの時間(リカバリー通知も)
      group_interval: 5m

      # 一度通知したアラートは1時間おきに通知
      repeat_interval: 1h

      # レシーバ対応先
      receiver: warning

receivers:
  - name: 'default'
    # slack_configs:
    # # Slack_apiのURL情報
    # - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'
    #   # Slack のチャンネル名
    #   channel: '#aws'
    #   title: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}[FIRING]{{else}}[RESOLVED]{{end}}{{ .GroupLabels.alertname }}'
    #   text: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}{{ .CommonAnnotations.firing_text }}{{else}}{{ .CommonAnnotations.resolved_text }}{{end}}'
    #   # 正常に戻った際に通知をする
    #   send_resolved: true
    email_configs:
    # mailの送信先
    # 正常に戻った際に通知をする
    - to: aaa@aaa.jp
      # title: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}[FIRING]{{else}}[RESOLVED]{{end}}{{ .GroupLabels.alertname }}'
      # text: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}{{ .CommonAnnotations.firing_text }}{{else}}{{ .CommonAnnotations.resolved_text }}{{end}}'
      # 正常に戻った際に通知をする
      send_resolved: true

  - name: 'critical'
    email_configs:
    # mailの送信先
    - to: aaa@aaa.jp
      # title: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}[FIRING]{{else}}[RESOLVED]{{end}}{{ .GroupLabels.alertname }}'
      # text: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}{{ .CommonAnnotations.firing_text }}{{else}}{{ .CommonAnnotations.resolved_text }}{{end}}'
      # 正常に戻った際に通知をする
      send_resolved: true
    # slack_configs:
    # Slack_apiのURL情報
    # - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'
      # Slack のチャンネル名
      # channel: '#aws'
      # title: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}[FIRING]{{else}}[RESOLVED]{{end}}{{ .GroupLabels.alertname }}'
      # text: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}{{ .CommonAnnotations.firing_text }}{{else}}{{ .CommonAnnotations.resolved_text }}{{end}}'
      # 正常に戻った際に通知をする
      # send_resolved: true

  - name: 'warning'
    slack_configs:
    # Slack_apiのURL情報
    # - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'
      # # Slack のチャンネル名
      # channel: '#aws'
      # title: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}[FIRING]{{else}}[RESOLVED]{{end}}{{ .GroupLabels.alertname }}'
      # text: '{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}{{ .CommonAnnotations.firing_text }}{{else}}{{ .CommonAnnotations.resolved_text }}{{end}}'
      # # 正常に戻った際に通知をする
      # send_resolved: true

inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
     # アラートの深刻度(severity) が critical の場合
     severity: 'critical' 
    target_match:
    # 同一のアラート名で warning のものは通知しない
     severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname']
```

Previously, I was unsuccessful even after adding the following as shown below

```
route:
- match:
　　　　job_name = www.abcdefg.com
     -alert_name = export_down

      # 同一アラート名、インスタンス名、エラーレベルでグループ化。アラートを同じ種類とみなす条件
      group_by: ['alertname', 'instance', 'severity']

      # 同じ種類のアラートを1つのアラート群としてにまとめる時間
      group_wait: 30s

      # 同じ種類のアラートが発生した時に次回通知するまでの時間(リカバリー通知も)
      group_interval: 5m

      # 一度通知したアラートは1時間おきに通知
      repeat_interval: 1h

      # レシーバ対応先
      receiver: customer



receivers:
  - name: 'customer'  
    email_configs:
    - to: bbb@bbb.jp
      send_resolved: true
```

Comment: It is unclear what you problem. Phrases like " was unsuccessful" without explanation what is not like you expected aren't helpful. Try to explain in more details what you want, and how your attempt failed at achieving it.

Comment: Also you are speaking about rules, but don't show rules. I don't know how relevant they are to question, because question is not clear, but if it relates to them, it's probably a good idea to add some information about them, and maybe example.